# nil values return error undefined method `car_number' for nil:NilClass even if I check them with .nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

when I replace the nil values manually with data, I get no errors.

```
<%  @visits.each do |f|  %>
<tr>
    <td><%=f.owner.car_number unless f.owner.car_number.nil?%></td>
    <td><%=f.owner.car_type unless f.owner.car_type.nil?%></td>
    <td><%=f.owner.car_year unless f.owner.car_year.nil?%></td>
    <td><%=f.owner.first_name unless f.owner.first_name.nil?%> <%=f.owner.last_name unless f.owner.last_name.nil?%></td>
    <td><%=f.owner.phone unless f.owner.phone.nil?%></td>
    <td style="direction:ltr"><%=f.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")%></td>
    <td>XX NOTES </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I feel my code is not DRY checking if nil? for each field, any suggestions for a better way to check .nil?s

Comment: we need to add validation on model visit to check presence of owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you need to add validation to stop entry of `nil` on `owner` in `visit` or the model where the association has defined to owner with visit

here I am consider here `visit model` has one `owner`

```
 class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :owner
     validates :owner, presence: true
 end
```

Or another solution using `try`

```
  <%  @visits.each do |f|  %>
  <tr>
    <% ["car_number", "car_type","car_year", "first_name", "last_name", "phone"].each do |meth| %>
      <td><%= f.try(:owner).send(meth) %></td>
    <% end %>
     <td style="direction:ltr"><%=f.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")%></td>
     <td>XX NOTES </td> 
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: you may be right but your answer is based on assumptions. OP has no where specified `@visits` belong to `Visit` model. It can very well be a simple instance variable created by OP in their controller.

Comment: yes I just guess it can be the Visit model or I am edit that too

Comment: I think you should mention all assumptions in your answer. It may confuse readers or attract downvotes otherwise. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `@visits` contains valid list of objects.

Now, lets read the error carefully:

> undefined method `car_number' for nil:NilClass

Where are you applying `car_number`? Hint: to object `f.owner`. Meaning `f.owner` is `nil` , so `f.owner.car_number.nil` will still throw an error.

Tweak them to:

```
<%= f.owner.car_number if f.owner %>
```

Or better:

```
<%  @visits.each do |f|  %>
  <tr>
    <% if f.owner %>
      <td><%=f.owner.car_number %></td>
      <td><%=f.owner.car_type %></td>
      <td><%=f.owner.car_year %></td>
      <td><%=f.owner.first_name %> <%=f.owner.last_name %></td>
      <td><%=f.owner.phone %></td>
      <td style="direction:ltr"><%=f.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")%></td>
      <td>XX NOTES </td>        
    <% end %>
  </tr>
```

Comment: this way I skip printing out any data if any field is .nil, however.
if f.car_type is nil?, all data will be skipped ....

Comment: Can you please give me one example when `f.owner` is `nil` and it still have other attributes like `car_number`, `car_type` etc? Thats impossible. I think you are fundamentally wrong. You need to check the value of `@visits` object. Also check your code design.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker true. However in this case OP will end up using it repeatedly in all individual lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check the first iteration.

Instead of :

```
unless f.owner.car_number.nil?
```

Use..

```
unless f.owner.nil?
```

Or you can check first before iterating, like:

```
<% unless @visits.nil? %>
  <%  @visits.each do |f|  %>
  ....
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```